# Why docker is not able to build image out of Dockerfile ? Is it m1 chip issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

Please share the possible solution.
I am trying to build docker image out of Dockerfile, but its taking infinite time to complete, it gets stuck in last step.

I am running on imac m1 chip.
Is seems issue with m1 chip.

I have create the react project using npx create-react-app react-app.
I have attached the code below/

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install 

COPY . . 

RUN ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: 'version'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file excluding the host's `node_modules` directory?  The `volumes:` block will cause Docker to ignore the effects of this change; does removing this block make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

RUN ["npm", "run", "start" ]

to be changed to

CMD ["npm", "run",

Comment: So the problem (the reason it appeared to "hang") was that your Dockerfile had "RUN" (instead of "CMD"), correct?  SUGGESTION: Please [Edit] this reply and copy/paste the complete, corrected Dockerfile, along with a bit of explanation.